# SQL Server: Stored procedure to update field using count

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have never written a stored procedure before. How would i go about updating a field in Table A with the results of a count of records in Table B that share a key?

Table A is a "users" table with a Primary key "userid" and a field "rentals_count". Table B is a "rentals" table with a Foreign Key "userid"

For each user (record) in Table A update the "rentals_count" field with the sum of rentals in Table B that match that user as an integer.

The question includes the mechanics of actually implementing and running the stored procedure on a nightly basis.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: The "concept" that is being relayed is "derived table".  See this for a basic example : http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/112098-1.shtml

Comment: Thanks. Helpful link there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `SQL Server`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTableA
AS
UPDATE  a
SET     a.rentals_count = b.totalCount
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  userID, Count(*) totalCount
            FROM    TableB
            GROUP   BY userID
        ) b ON a.userID = b.userID
```

For `MySQL`

```
UPDATE  TableA a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  userID, Count(*) totalCount
            FROM    TableB
            GROUP   BY userID
        ) b ON a.userID = b.userID
SET     a.rentals_count = b.totalCount
```